# Why does the counter keep counting when i'm using .hasNext in file io in java

Tags: java

Basically, I'm trying to count how many lines in a txt file and then store it to an array as index.

```
File file = new java.io.File("number.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
int count = 0;
while(s.hasNextLine())
{     
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
System.out.println("There is: " + count + " line );
int[] array = new int[count];
```

However, I realize that the "count" go infinity and it never stop counting, but I only have 20 line in my txt file. Why is this happening??

Note: I know how to fix , but i just curious about why it keep counting

Comment: Because you never make the `Scanner` move to the next line via `s.nextLine()`...

Comment: The line is still there until you read it.

Comment: "I know how to fix" so how would you fix it? How do you think fix is working?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using

```
scanner.nextLine()
```

in conjunction with

```
scanner.hasNextLine()
```

hasNextLine will check if the there is next line available or not but it will not goto the next line for that you need to use nextLine. When both of them are used you will see the counter stop after it has parsed the last line. So your code should be something like this

```
File file = new java.io.File("number.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
int count = 0;
while(s.hasNextLine())
{   
    s.nextLine();
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
System.out.println("There is: " + count + " line );
int[] array = new int[count];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that is the way it is designed.

> public boolean hasNextLine()
>
> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
>   This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.
>
> Returns:
>       true if and only if this scanner has another line of input 
>   Blockquote
>
> Throws:
>       IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

Comment: is this the reason why when i declare a variable in the while loop             var =s.nextInt() it will go to next line, but  without it, it will keep staying on the first line of the file?

Comment: Yes, as the above javadoc already mentioned, hasNexLine() does not advance past any input, but nextInt() will (or at least tries to).